# Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "_a" while scraping angel list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been workin on scraping company data from angelist csv file and i want to get the fist name, last name and role title of the founders. For this I am using Requests with Beautiful Soup. I think i am doingsomething wrong with soup.select.

This is the current Nested tree of classes

```
-founders section
--section with_filler with_editable_regions dsss17 startups-show-sections ffs70 founders _a _jm
---dsr31 startup_roles fsp87 startup_profile_group _a _jm
----ul.larger roles
-----li.role
------<<dynamic div>>
-------g-lockup top larger
--------photo
--------text
---------name
---------role_title
---------bio
```

and here is the sample page URL https://angel.co/dealflicks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element
req = requests.get('https://angel.co/dealflicks', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
print(req.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")

founders = soup.select('.founders section .section with_filler with_editable_regions dsss17 startups-show-sections ffs70 founders _a _jm .dsr31 startup_roles fsp87 startup_profile_group _a _jm .larger roles role')

print (founders)
```

It is throwing me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 11, in <module>
    founders = soup.select('.founders section .section with_filler 
with_editable_regions dsss17 startups-show-sections ffs70 founders _a _jm 
.dsr31 startup_roles fsp87 startup_profile_group _a _jm .larger roles 
role')
  File "C:\Users\nandi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 
1477, in select
    'Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "%s"' % token)
ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "_a"
```

Comment: You should read about how CSS selectors work. In your case the `_a` would match a `<_a>` tag which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

it is because the `_a` is a class not tag name or `<_a>` you need to prefix the value for class with the dot `.` or use it with `findAll()`

```
soup.findAll('div', class='section with_filler with_editable_regions dsss17 startups-show-sections ffs70 founders _a _jm')
```

but you only need this simple selectors

```
founders = soup.select('ul.larger.roles li')
print (founders)
```

or copy the selectors from elements panel in web developer tools

```
founders = soup.select('#root > div.page.flush_bottom.dl85.layouts.fhr17.header._a._jm > div > div.content.s-grid.s-grid--outer.u-maxWidthLayout.s-vgBottom2 > div > div.s-flexgrid0.s-flexgrid0--fixed.panes_grid > div.main.pane.s-flexgrid0--footer.s-flexgrid0-colMdW.s-vgPadRight1 > div > div.founders.section > div > div > ul > li')
```